# oracle cloud infrastructure sign-in notauthorized

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a free account for the past 4 months on oracle cloud, it has a tenancy in Frankfurt and it has a vm computing instance
my free tier was expired about 3 months ago and i continued with always free resources, since then it worked just fine until they suddenly sent me a mail stating that my account free tier has ended (again!!) and that i was limited to always free resources.
i tried to connect to my vm but obviously it is down, when i log in to oracled cloud admin console it is working but when i log to the infrastructure dashboard it show me a page just saying :
{
"code" : "NotAuthenticated",
"message" : "The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect."
}
and they have exclusive support for paid accounts only.
so is there any help ?

Comment: Talk to Oracle support. Random people on the internet cannot solve this for you.

Comment: [From the FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/faq/): "How do I get help if I have problems signing up or signing in?" says "Contact the Oracle Cloud support team using the Chat link in the menu bar."

Comment: Althoug I mentioned above that they have their support only for paid memberships, lets make it simpler by saying that I did contacted them but there was no response from them.